# Issue regarding parsing a file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, file, parsing

I have a text file (.txt) which contains an array and the elements of these array is in string format but these are also arrays. Just like the following:

For example, lets consider my file as:

```
["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]
```

Now I want to parse these file and I need to print the data in the following format as:

```
1   2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000   ho

1   2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000   hose

1   2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000   mo
```

Now , I just don't know where to start. I know how to parse a text file in ruby but this time its containing an array. So I am confused how to start and did not get the right idea yet.

Please help me by giving me some hints.

Thanks in advance!!!

I am using the following code to store the content of the file into the array. But it is not giving me the proper format. My file contains array in a contiguous manner. There is no new line in it. I think it causing the problem in the following code.

```
arr=[]

arr=File.foreach('input.txt').map { |line| line.split(' ') }
```

Comment: is it possible for you to change file contents to something like `1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, "ho" \n 1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, "ho"`

Comment: or you want to parse the file as it is?

Comment: I want to parse the file as it is. Its a system generated file.

Comment: Does the file only have one line, exactly written as it is?

Comment: It is a single array of this format.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it isn't an Array, but a string which contains what looks like an Array.

Comment: No, just look at the outermost [] brackets. It does signify that it is an array whose elements are string but looking like another array. I just need to print the data of the inner string like array sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

You could use json to parse your file, which looks like an Array of Strings :

```
require 'json'
array = JSON.parse(File.read('file.txt')).map{|string| string.delete('[],"')}
```

Your array now looks like this :

```
  ["1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho",
   "1 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000 hose cla",
   "1 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000 mo"]
```

If you want the first line, just use `array.first`.

## Old answer

This is probably the easiest way, with [chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove newlines at the end of each line, and [delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-delete) to remove all the specified characters :

```
array = ["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]

puts array.map{|string| string.chomp.delete('[],"')}
#=> ["1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho",
#    "1 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000 hose cla",
#    "1 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000 mo"]
```

To just show the first line :

```
puts array.map{|string| string.chomp.delete('[],"')}[0]
#=> "1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho"
```

Comment: Ok,,,Now I can read the file and array is created. But the above code is not showing the desired result. I used puts array.map{|string| string.chomp.delete('[],"')}

Comment: Moreover if I want only "1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho" to be printed ,then what should I write?

Comment: Updated answer. Just take the first element of the array.

Comment: This is the best way I think,,,Thanks a lot @Eric Duminil

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]

arr.map{ |str| str.gsub(/[\[\]\\",]/, '') }

#=> [
#=>  "1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho",
#=>  "1 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000 hose cla",
#=>  "1 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000 mo"
#=> ]
```

Now you can do whatever you want over the data

**EDIT:**

> how to put the content of my file into this array variable?

You can read file with

```
arr = File.readlines("#{Rails.root}/file.txt").map(&:strip)
```

**`strip`** is just to remove any additional spaces

Comment: how to put the content of my file into this array variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
array = ["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]

array.each do |a|
  puts a.gsub(/[\[\]\\",]/, '')
end
```

Output:

```
1 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000 ho
1 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000 hose cla
1 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000 mo
```

To read File

```
array = File.readlines('path/to/file.txt')
```

Comment: how to put the content of my file into this array variable?